# Authenticate a Cognito user without Federation in Unity

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, amazon-cognito

I've been digging through AWS documentation but have not been able to find an example of using an unfederated login method for cognito in a Unity application.

For example:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforunity/developerguide/aws-unity-dg.pdf
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforunity/developerguide/getting-started-unity.html

In all of this documentation I can't find a single reference for authenticating a user *without* using a federated identity method, such as facebook.  Is there just no support for this in their SDK?  Am I stuck using the HTTP API?

If anyone has any samples or experience I would much appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 2):

This example from AWS uses Unity with GameLift has code utilizing a Cognito user pool (not an identity user pool with federated login).

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/gametech/creating-servers-for-multiplayer-mobile-games-with-amazon-gamelift/

Within the RTSClient.cs it makes a direct AWS Cognito API call in C# using the AWS SDK. That is one possible way, or you could have that logic within a lambda function behind API Gateway that your client reaches out to.